# How to monitor changes in an attribute? (as opposted to change /of/ the attribute)

Tags: perl, attributes, moose

Often I use Perl/Moose attributes that hold a collection of objects. I know it's possible to monitor if the attribute as a whole is set. In that case a [trigger](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/FLORA/Moose-0.96/lib/Moose/Manual/Attributes.pod#Triggers) can be used. This makes it also possible to monitor objects in an attribute. But how to monitor the collection? Is it possible to monitor if an object is added if the attribute is - for example - an array of objects?

What I'm looking for is a kind of [method modifier](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/FLORA/Moose-0.99/lib/Moose/Manual/Concepts.pod#Method_modifiers) such as "before" or "around" for when a build-in function such as push or shift is called on an attribute. This would allow for very general solutions for things like only save if there are changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operations like `push` are not performed on the attribute itself, but on the array object referenced by that attribute.

The only reliable way to observe such operations is therefore from within that array object – by [`tie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tie.html)-ing it to an appropriate class. But this is fairly dark Perl magic and generally inadvisable (slow, difficult to do correctly, may expose bugs in other modules, and very low-level).

The often better approach is to choose a design that stops exposing an array reference. E.g. instead of `push @{ $foo->attribute }, 42` you might offer a method `$foo->push_attribute(42)`. In that method you can implement any hooks you need.

Comment: The option of defining a method occurred to me. Downside is that it's not a general solution. Tie-ing did not occur to me. What did occur to me was subclassing Tie::IxHash, with MooseX::NonMoose. Which has about the same result. Perhaps that would be the best course of action.